# Resources for the Redis course

Tags: resource-request, databases

What optimal resources you could recommend for a small Redis course with a preliminary academic foundation at the beginning of the book?
I would be grateful for an applied university-level curriculum if one exists.

Comment: Redis is an "in memory" database.

Comment: Your requirements seem inconsistent. "University level" implies the student has background.

Comment: RedisLabs provides [courses](https://university.redislabs.com/#courses) on redis, which may be useful to look into. How far is your class expected to go?

Comment: @thesecretmaster for about 3-4 weeks, 10-13 topics we plan to cover